# Goodman furnace flames out after 5 mins from cold start

Tags: hvac

Problem with Goodman Furnace flaming out. After it has been off for about an hour it will flame out after it starts and runs for 5-10 min before it satisfies themo setting. Restarts and finishes cycle. Next time it will usually run thru cycle. Pipes are two inch and run 31 feet out back of condo. Will run fine after a few cycles.

This is a Gas Furnace. Goodman GMSS960603BN Model no. 96% PSC UF New. Single stage,up flow. Has 2 inch pipe that runs out the back of condo. 31 feet. Two pipes, intake air and vent pipe. Manual say can use 2 inch pipe with 4- 90 degree elbows and run 30 ft. HAD 2 TECHS that say it is pipe problem. Why will it run full cycle most of the time. Then act up after it has been off cycle for about an hour or longer. Condensation water is draining. No kinks in hoses in furnace. Flame out t(All burners stop producing flame. Since is new pressure switch and control board have not been checked. I now have intake pipe off and use house air to get heat. Getting ready to have a 3 rd tech come in and go over everything. Any suggestion to tell him, will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it gas or oil? What do you mean "flame out"? Does that mean the flame goes crazy and stops or the flame just turns off? What are the pipes you're talking about?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can help you; please edit it into your question.

Comment: Model numbers really help Goodman makes many different types of systems open combustion, closed combustion high efficiency models and different things go wrong depending on the type.

Comment: Look for a diagnostic or fault indicator, likely visible through a window in the blower compartment. It may be showing a repeating pattern of flashes or blinks. Count these and look for a label, maybe on the inside of the blower door, which tells how to interpret the signal. That'll help determine why the furnace shuts down.

Comment: @manassehkatz I bet Wilson here say a textbox that  indicated  “title” and thought it was his job title, not the title of his question 

Comment: Quick check to see if it is a venting issue...unhook the intake and allow it to use air from inside the furnace location. Run it with a shorter pipe, or no pipe and see if it continues to operate in the manner described, or if it functions properly. If so, you have a venting issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had a brand new Goodman furnace in our new condo do something similar a year after we bought our brand new condo. It would flame out multiple times, and then randomly decide to start working again. I'm not knowledgeable at all regarding anything HVAC, but I tried diagnosing all the different switches/sensors and came to my own conclusion that it was the control board as everything else appeared fine.

Asked for a technician to come and check it out and bring a replacement board; They forgot/neglected to bring the board, ran the same checks as I did and a bit more, but couldn't determine the problem. I rescheduled, this time insisting more assertively to bring a replacement board; They did on the second attempt and it has worked fine ever since.

Those hardware boards seem to be quite unreliable from what I've heard. It can't hurt to ask them to bring a replacement board to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the venting. It should retry ignition on its own but if you are over the allowed distance for venting it will continue to act up. The flash codes should tell you if it's tripping of on the pressure switch. I think that model has a little window on the bottom door. If you are getting 2 flashes or 3 flashes your venting is too long. You can increase a portion of it to 3" venting and that may do the trick but it's recommended to change all of it to 3".